# Change default renderer - Android

Tags: android, android-layout

I would like to alter the way all colors are being displayed by a device running Android OS, after executing my app.
As I imagine, I would need to load a different rendering object over the OS's default one.

Is it possible? (without compiling my own ROM).

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry to say, that is not possible.

Comment: Unless you application requested root; in which case you might be able to do it then. Even so, though you may be creating a 'theme' app, I do not think that this is really required. What do you want to do this for?